# Closed Form of Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have tried this integral in Mathematica,

```
Assuming[m > 0,Integrate[Cos[m k] Exp[ Cos[k]], {k, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

And Mathematica failed to perform this. Whereas if any value of m is declared then it is showing the result in terms of Modified Bessel Function. I want to know the reason why Mathematica can not perform the integral in the general term of m, but performing this integral when the value of m is declared.

Comment: For fixed `m` I get a result, for example `Integrate[Cos[3 k] Exp[Cos[k]], {k, 0, 2 Pi}]` `(* 2 \[Pi] BesselI[3, 1] *)`

Comment: But `Integrate[Cos[3/2* k] Exp[Cos[k]], {k, 0, 2 Pi}]` gives a result of zero. So the general formula with the Bessel function probably only applies to integers.

Comment: `Integrate[Cos[17*k] Exp[Cos[k]], {k, 0, 2 *Pi}]` performs $$2 \pi  (183252363823720801 I_1(1)-762935687373888144 I_2(1)) .$$

Comment: `N[2 \[Pi] (183252363823720801 BesselI[1, 1] - 762935687373888144 BesselI[2, 1]), 50]` is equal to `N[ 2 \[Pi] BesselI[17, 1], 50]`

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec:  That can presumably be proven analytically using the identity $I_{n+1}(z) = \frac{2n}{z} I_n(z) + I_{n-1}(z)$.  And Mathematica returns `True` from  `FullSimplify[(183252363823720801 BesselI[1, 1] - 
    762935687373888144 BesselI[2, 1]) == BesselI[17, 1]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is probably that the formula with the Bessel function only applies to some `m` and in general it will be more complicated. Take a look at the following graph.

```
Show[Plot[NIntegrate[Cos[m* k] Exp[Cos[k]], {k, 0, 2 Pi}], {m, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[2*Pi*BesselI[m, 1], {m, 0, 5}]]
```

[image]